# scalaz's Applicative#point Method?

Tags: scalaz, applicative

Why does scalaz's [Applicative.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala#L22) have `point` method?

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Apply[F] { self =>
  ////
  def point[A](a: => A): F[A]

  // alias for point
  final def pure[A](a: => A): F[A] = point(a)
```

Perhaps it could just have a `def pure` method without the **final** accessor and `point`?

Answer (score 3):

There's a long history of design decisions and historical accidents here. In Scalaz 6 there was a type class called [`Pure`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/6.0.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Pure.scala) and another called [`Pointed`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/6.0.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Pointed.scala) (which extended `Pure`). Back then there was no `point` method, just `pure`.

Then both `Pure` and `Pointed` were discarded (for various reasons) and the `point` method was added to `Applicative` (which used to be `Pointed` plus `Apply`). The `pure` alias was kept around because historically that's what this operation was called in Scalaz.

So sure, you could just have `point` (Cats only has [`pure`](https://github.com/non/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Applicative.scala)), and it's possible that some future version of Scalaz might get rid of the alias. They're just names.

Comment: Can you explain why `Pure` was removed from Scalaz?